# MySQL: Select multiple records with comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: `store_products`, `store_orders` and `store_orders_products`. `store_products` contains all of the products, `store_orders` contains the order information, and `store_orders_products` contains each individual product in that order.

I'm building an Orders page that will list each order placed. It will have the username of the person who placed the order, the date, the total amount and the name of each product.

This query gets me everything I want, except it returns only ONE product name. I want to have each product in a comma separated string. I've tried subqueries, `COALESCE`, `CONCAT`, `IN()`, etc, but I'm not getting the results I want.

```
SELECT 
    o.id AS order_id
    , o.order_total
    , o.created_at
    , u.username
    , u.avatar
    , sp.name 
FROM store_orders o 
JOIN store_orders_contents c ON o.id=c.oid 
JOIN store_products p ON p.id=c.pid
JOIN users u ON u.id=o.consumer_uid
JOIN store_products sp ON sp.id=c.pid
WHERE p.uid=3
GROUP BY order_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.order_total, o.created_at, u.username, u.avatar,
       group_concat(sp.name )
FROM store_orders o JOIN
     store_orders_contents c
     ON o.id = c.oid JOIN
     store_products p
     ON p.id = c.pid JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = o.consumer_uid JOIN
     store_products sp
     ON sp.id = c.pid
WHERE p.uid = 3
GROUP BY order_id;
```

I don't understand why you are joining to `store_products` twice, but I assume you know what you are doing with the joins.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I actually tried `group_concat()` earlier today and then, after reworking the query totally forgot about it! The second join on `store_products` is from me playing around in sequel pro. it's gone now. :)

Comment: NOTE: The maximum length of the return from GROUP_CONCAT is limited by the setting of `group_concat_max_len` variable (default value I believe is 1024. Good practice would be to check the length of the returned value, to determine whether the value may have been truncated.